# Returning variables outside a function

Tags: jquery, return

I have been having problems returning a variable through a jQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = "";

    $('.whitetheme').on('click', function () {
        $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
        selected = "whitetheme";
        return selected;

        $('.blacktheme').fadeOut(1500);
        $('.redtheme').fadeOut(1500);

    })

    console.log(selected);
});
```

I am trying to have the value of selected changed to "whitetheme" once it is clicked.

Right now, the log function returns an empty string.

Comment: is it returning an empty string after the click event? Noticed that you're logging the value before it's been updated...

Answer (score 3):

You're binding an event handler which would (and will if invoked) change the variable value. However, the event cannot occur before the `console.log` is executed, so that you don't see the updated value.

Also, your `blacktheme` and `redtheme` classes will not get faded out, since that code part is unreachable.

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to set the variable "selected" a string value

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it up a little like this so your console.log prints out after you click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected = "";

    $('.whitetheme').on('click', function () {
        $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
        selected = "whitetheme";
        // return selected; don't need this or the next 2 lines won't execute

        $('.blacktheme').fadeOut(1500);
        $('.redtheme').fadeOut(1500);

        console.log("selected: "+selected);
    });
    // console.log(selected); moved above
});
```

Comment: I need to log the value outside of the function though

Comment: You can log the value outside also, but the value won't be updated until the user clicks on the 'whitetheme' element, so your empty string will be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

To go along with my question/comment above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var selected = "";

$('.whitetheme').on('click', function(){
$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
selected = "whitetheme";

/*Moved this line*/
console.log(selected);

return selected;
$('.blacktheme').fadeOut(1500);
$('.redtheme').fadeOut(1500);

})
});
```